# Pandas - number of rows and groupby in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have [this data set](https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/api/views/icn6-v9z3/rows.csv) and I want to display the columns ('Police District Name', 'Number of Crimes') for all crimes with more than 3 victims. However, the column 'Number of Crimes' does not exists and show be created, and it indicates (and the total number of crimes committed in that district). Note: every row indicates 1 crime.

Sample of the data set:

```
Incident ID Victims Police District Name Beat
0   201087096   1      GERMANTOWN        5N1
1   201087097   1        WHEATON         4K2
2   201087097   1        WHEATON         4K2
3   201087097   1        WHEATON         4K2
4   201087100   1      GERMANTOWN        5M1
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

crimes_df = pd.read_csv('data/Crime.csv', low_memory=False, dtype={'Incident ID': int, 'Beat':object})
more_than_three_victims = crimes_df[(crimes_df['Victims'] > 3)]
more_than_three_victims.groupby(['Police District Name']).sum()
```

I have no idea what to do from here, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please include a minimal sample of your dataset and a desired output.  People shouldn't have to download an unknown csv to answer

Comment: wait so you only want those 2 columns? not all 26?

Comment: @user3483203 Thank you for notifying me. Edited.

Comment: @d_kennetz Exactly.

Comment: Is a crime defined as a new `Incident ID` or a new row in the dataset?  In your sample Incident ID `201087097` has 1 victim but shows up 3 times so does this mean it has 3 victims for the one crime referenced by the `incident ID`?

Comment: Do you want count of total crimes or count of crimes with > 3 victims

Comment: @jtweeder No, only if the column 'victims' has a value greater than 3.

Comment: It's still a simple case of groupby and count, df.groupby(['Police District Name'])['Incident ID'].count().reset_index(name = 'Number of Crimes')

Comment: @user3483203 count of crimes with > 3 victims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to initially read in your data, you don't have to create a df from all of your columns:

```
crimes_df = pd.read_csv('./Desktop/Crime.csv', usecols=['Police District Name', 'Victims'])
# The above will only read in the columns listed
more_than_three_victims = crimes_df[(crimes_df['Victims'] > 3)] # filter based on 3 crimes
groupby_victims = more_than_three_victims.groupby('Police District Name')['Victims'].agg(['sum']).rename(columns = {'sum': 'Number of Victims'})
print(groupby_victims)
```

output:

```
                      Number of Victims
Police District Name                  
BETHESDA                            52
GERMANTOWN                         106
MONTGOMERY VILLAGE                 104
ROCKVILLE                           73
SILVER SPRING                      107
TAKOMA PARK                          4
WHEATON                             78
```

This groups by Police District Name and sums the number of victims in each distict, and then renames the column 'sum' to Number of Crimes. I believe this is what you were looking for.

If you want to count the number of crimes with > 3 victims:

```
groupby_victims = more_than_three_victims.groupby('Police District Name')['Victims'].agg(['count']).rename(columns ={'count': 'Number of Crimes'})
# you just change 'sum' to 'count'
```

output:

```
                      Number of Crimes
Police District Name                  
BETHESDA                             9
GERMANTOWN                          23
MONTGOMERY VILLAGE                  21
ROCKVILLE                           15
SILVER SPRING                       21
TAKOMA PARK                          1
WHEATON                             18
```

Again, this will be the number of crimes, not the sum of victims.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: So this will actually sum the number of victims, do you want a count of the number of crimes with >3 victims? I will post an edit to show how it should change if so

Comment: Yes, I want the number of crimes with > 3

Comment: see edit, it is a super easy fix

Comment: Seen, and greatly appreciated! Thank you once again :D